# Calculating the gradient of Log-Euclidean distance between SPD matrices on Riemannian manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, matrix-norms

In the paper [Log-Euclidean metrics for fast and simple calculus on diffusion tensors](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mrm.20965),
the geodesic distance between SPD matrices $A,B$ is defined as
$$d(A,B)=||\log A- \log B||_F,$$
where $F$ is the Frobenius norm. I did not find more information on the other aspects of the Riemannian structure.

I am interested in the gradient (on Riemannian manifold) of the distance function
$$
f(X) = d(X,A_0).
$$
I am not familiar with geometry other than some basics, $\langle grad f,X\rangle = Xf $ for all smooth vector field $X$.

How can I derive $grad f$?

Comment: the link to the paper is broken....

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\f{\frac{\tt1}{f}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{{\cal A}}\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\z#1{\op{\zeta}\!\LR{#1}}
\def\smA{{\small A}}
\def\smB{{\small B}}
$Introduce the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
 A &= X,\quad &L = \log(A), \quad &L_0 = \log(A_0) \\
}$$
Since $A$ is positive definite it can be diagonalized
$$A=QBQ^T,\quad B=\Diag{b},\quad Q^TQ=I$$

First calculate the differential of the distance function $f$
$$\eqalign{
f^2 &= \|L-L_0\|^2_F \\
 &= \LR{L-L_0}:\LR{L-L_0} \\
2f\;df &= 2\LR{L-L_0}:dL \\
df &= \f\LR{L-L_0}:dL \\
df &= G:\c{dL} \qiq G \doteq \fracLR{L-L_0}{f} \\
}$$
Now invoke the [Daleckii-Krein](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2466/1/gendk.pdf) theorem $\:\big(\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product$\big)$
$$\eqalign{
\c{dL} &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TdA\,Q}}Q^T \\
}$$
Substituting this into the previous differential leads to
the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:\c{Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TdA\,Q}}Q^T} \\
 &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TG\,Q}}Q^T:dA \\
\grad{f}{A} &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TG\,Q}}Q^T \\
}$$
The final task is to evaluate the $R$ matrix which lies at the heart of the theorem. This can be done using the log function and its derivative $\left\{\log(x),\frac{1}{x}\right\}$ evaluated at $B$, an *all-ones* matrix $J$, and $\z{X}$ which is an elementwise $\c{\sf zero\:indicator}$ function
$$\eqalign{
\z{X}_{ij} &= \begin{cases}
\o\qquad {\rm if}\;X_{ij}=0 \\
0\qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
Z &= \z{BJ-JB},\qquad L_\smB = \log(B),\qquad L_\smB' = B^{-1} \\
R &= {\frac{L_\smB J-JL_\smB+ZL_\smB'}{BJ-JB+Z}}
 \qquad \big({\rm Hadamard\;division}\big) \\\\
}$$
or in terms of the components of the $b$ vector
$$\eqalign{
R_{jk} &= \begin{cases} 
{\Large\frac{\log(b_j)\,-\,\log(b_k)}{b_j\,-\,b_k}} \quad{\rm if}\; b_j\ne b_k \\
\\
\qquad\quad {\Large\frac{\o}{b_k}} \qquad\qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}\\
\\
}$$

---

Note that some of the steps above use the Frobenius product $(A:B)$, which is an extremely useful product notation for the trace function
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \trace{A^TB} \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \big({\rm hence\;the\;name}\big) \\
}$$
Note that the Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C)
\;=\; (A\odot B):C
\;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
There are also easily derived rules for rearranging product terms, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
A:B &= B:A \\
(AC^T):B &= A:(BC) = (B^TA):C  \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

This could be derived step by step, using chain rules

1. Frobenious norm. Let's deal with the squared norm first! taking sqrt is easy.
   $$
   d(A,B)^2=\|A-B\|^2_F = tr((A-B)^T(A-B)) = \sum_{ij} (A_{ij}-B_{ij})^2
   $$
   So if one of the matrices $A$ is a function of a scalar $t$
   $$
   \frac{\partial d(A(t),B)^2}{\partial t} = 2\sum_{ij} (A_{ij}-B_{ij})\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial t}\\
   =2tr((A-B)^T\frac{\partial A}{\partial t})
   $$
   One specific case is
   $$
   \frac{\partial d(A,B)^2}{\partial A_{ij}} = 2(A_{ij}-B_{ij})\\
   $$
   So we can write $$\frac{\partial d(A,B)^2}{\partial A}=2(A-B)$$

Getting rid of the square
$$
\frac{\partial d(A(t),B)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} d^{-1/2}\cdot 2tr((A-B)^T\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}) = d^{-1/2}tr((A-B)^T\frac{\partial A}{\partial t})
$$

2. matrix logrithm (See [Derivative of matrix logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837070/derivative-of-matrix-logarithm))
   $$
   \frac{\partial \log(X(t))}{\partial t} = X(t)^{-1} \frac{\partial X(t)}{\partial t}
   $$
   We can think of the entry $X_{ij}$ as a parameter of $X$, then we get $$\frac{\partial X(t)}{\partial X_{ij}}=E_{ij}$$ .$E_{ij}$ is a matrix which only $i,j$ element is 1, others are all $0$.
3. Using chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial d(X,A_0)^2}{\partial X_{ij}} =\partial_{X_{ij}} \|\log X -\log A_0\|^2_F \\
= 2tr\left((\log X -\log A_0)^T \frac{\partial \log X}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X} {\partial X_{ij}}\right)\\
=2 tr\left((\log X -\log A_0)^T (X^{-1}E_{ij})\right)
$$

Note that the effect $E_{ij}$ in the trace operator is quite unique
Since
$$
tr(A^TB) = \sum{ij} A_{ij}B_{ij}\\
tr(M^TE_{kl}) = \sum{ij} M_{ij}E_{ij} = M_{kl}
$$
$E_{ij}$ works as a delta function in getting the entry.

Thus taking the element wise derivative together and form a matrix
$$
\left(\frac{\partial d(X,A_0)^2}{\partial X}\right)_{ij} = 2 tr((\log X -\log A_0)^T (X^{-1}E_{ij}))\\
\frac{\partial d(X,A_0)^2}{\partial X} = 2 X^{-1}(\log X -\log A_0)\\
\frac{\partial d(X,A_0)}{\partial X} = d^{-1/2} X^{-1}(\log X -\log A_0)
$$

Comment: The first formula in Step #2 is not correct, unless X commutes with $\left(\frac{dX}{dt}\right)\;$ Have a look at the first part of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4269651/357854) for the derivative of the logarithm when the matrices don't commute.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I ll integrate that

Comment: In case you want to double-check your algebra, I got
$$\eqalign{
f &= d(X,A_0) \\
W &= (X+I)^{-1}(X-I) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}
 &= \frac1f\Bigg[X^{-1}\log(X)
 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}
  \left(\frac{W^{j-1}(I-W)\;\log(A_0)\;(I-W)W^{2k+1-j}}{2k+1}\right)\Bigg] \\
}$$