# How to handle integral with matrix and trace

Tags: integration, matrix-calculus

I have some problem to manage a scalar function integral that involves matrix and trace, and I'm hoping somebody can help me out. I have to solve this ODE
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} C(\tau) =
    \mathrm{Tr}[\beta \mathbf{Q}^{T}\mathbf{Q} \mathbf{A}(\tau)] + \gamma r ,
    \quad C(0) = 0
$$
where $r>0,\beta>0$, $\gamma = iu, u\in\mathbb{R}$ the Fourier transform argument, $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{R},\mathbf{Q}\in M_{d}$ (set of square real matrix), $\mathbf{M}$ is negative semi-definite. $\mathbf{A}(\tau)$ is the solution of matrix riccati equation (and its solution is given by linearization)
$$
    \mathbf{A}(\tau) = \mathbf{F}(\tau)^{-1}\mathbf{G}(\tau)
$$
that leads to a solution of $2d$ system of linear ODEs
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} G(\tau) =
    \frac{\gamma(\gamma-1)}{2} \mathbf{F}(\tau) + \mathbf{G}(\tau)\mathbf{M}
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} F(\tau) =
    -\mathbf{F}(\tau)(\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q})
    - 2 \mathbf{G}(\tau) \mathbf{Q}^{T}\mathbf{Q}
$$
Now to solve equation for $C(\tau)$ we work on the equation for $d/d\tau [\mathbf{F}(\tau)]$ we obtain
$$
\mathbf{G}(\tau) = 
   -\frac{1}{2} 
    \left[
        \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} \mathbf{F}(\tau) 
        + \mathbf{F}(\tau) (\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q}) 
    \right] (\mathbf{Q}^{T}\mathbf{Q})^{-1}
$$
Now, we plug this in the equation for $C(\tau)$ and we substitute
$
    \mathbf{A}(\tau) = \mathbf{F}(\tau)^{-1}\mathbf{G}(\tau).
$
We obtain
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} C(\tau) =
    -\frac{\beta}{2}
    \mathrm{Tr}\left[ 
        \mathbf{F}(\tau)^{-1}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} \mathbf{F}(\tau) 
        + \mathbf{F}(\tau)(\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q})
     \right] 
    + \gamma r ,   
$$
Now we can integrate (using trace properties), so
$$
   C(\tau) =
   -\frac{\beta}{2} 
         \int_{0}^{\tau}
         \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[
         \mathbf{F}(s)^{-1}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \tau} \mathbf{F}(s) 
        \Bigr] ds
   -\frac{\beta}{2} 
         \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[(\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q})\Bigr] 
         \int_{0}^{\tau} ds
   +\gamma r \int_{0}^{\tau} ds
$$
and so
$$
   C(\tau) =
   -\frac{\beta}{2} 
         \int_{0}^{\tau}
         \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[
         \mathbf{F}(s)^{-1}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} s} \mathbf{F}(s) 
        \Bigr] ds
   -\frac{\beta}{2} 
         \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[(\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q})\Bigr] 
         \tau
   +\gamma r \tau
$$
The solution should be
$$
    C(\tau) =
   -\frac{\beta}{2} 
      \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[
            \log \mathbf{F}(\tau)
            + (\mathbf{M}^{T} + 2\gamma\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q})
           \tau
        \Bigr]
   +\gamma r \tau
$$
But I can't understand how to handle this term
$$
      -\frac{\beta}{2} 
         \int_{0}^{\tau}
         \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl[
         \mathbf{F}(s)^{-1}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} s} \mathbf{F}(s) 
        \Bigr] ds
$$
For completeness I report the [paper](https://www.dse.univr.it/documenti/RapportoRicercaEst/allegato/allegato975769.pdf) where the ODE appear (see page 8).

I forget also $\mathbf{Q}\in GL(d)$ admits inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the matrix generalization of the usual derivation rule of the logarithm, namely, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f(x)) = f(x)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}}f(x).$$

You can find a proof for the matrix case in the answer to this question [Derivative of matrix logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837070/derivative-of-matrix-logarithm).

Comment: Wonderful answer, I couldn't have asked for better, thank you very much (^-^)

Comment: you are welcome